# Remote desktop without a password

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have an HTPC with a user that has no password and autologin.

I want to be able to connect to it via *Remote Desktop* without a password, so I can login with the original user. (I don't want to add another user just for the mstsc)

Is there a way of doing that?

The OS is Windows 7, 32bit.

Comment: just beware that this would be a very bad security decision and consider firewalling it or at least do not forward the port out...

Comment: This is not a good idea.

Comment: Another solution:  Teamviewer.  Rather than running without a password it uses a stored password.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

By default, Windows will not allow the logon over a network with a blank password. There is a [KB article that details how to allow blank passwords for network logons](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303846).

---

You can disable blank password restrictions by using a policy. To locate and change this policy:

1. Click Start, point to Run, type gpedit.msc, and then click OK to start the Group Policy Editor.
2. Open Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only.
3. Double-click Limit local account use of blank passwords to consol logon only.
4. Click Disabled, and then click OK.
5. Quit Group Policy Editor.

NOTE: By default, this policy is on (enabled).

---

Under the cover, in Registry, this is controlled by

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000
```

Therefore, alternatively, this can be achieved by directly setting `LimitBlankPasswordUse` to `0`. Setting it to `1` will restore the default behavior.

---

After you have enabled this, you will be allowed to log on using a blank password.

Comment: I also have the same requirement. I am connecting to windows 2003 server machine from windows 7 machine using 'mstsc'. I have disabled the option "Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only". But still it prompting for password. Any suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: This is also a possible fix for the 0x80090304 authentication error using RDP. (Same problem, it just depends on whether you're connecting with NLA or without.)

Comment: +1; confirmed on windows 8 as well.

Comment: I beg to differ. We didn't have this enabled and someone got in via port forwarding and logged into an account with a blank password.

Comment: Worked on a Win10 installation that didn't have `gpedit.msc`. Changed the registry key and didn't even need to reboot :D

Answer (score 5):

I believe the setting should be DISABLED as the explanation here seems to indicate:

> This security setting determines whether local accounts that are not password protected can be used to log on from locations other than the physical computer console. If enabled, local accounts that are not password protected will only be able to log on at the computer's keyboard.
>
> Default: Enabled.

So, by disabling it, you can then log on using no password.

Comment: What setting? This answer should standalone and nor refer to another answer to this extent.  Please edit it to complete it.