# Mountain Lion Won't connect to my Windows 7 PC without password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, osx-mountain-lion, connection

For the last couple years I have had my Mac set up to connect to my Windows 7 account via my home network. I access my PC drives from my mac and vice versa. Up until August I used Snow Leopard.

I updated my Mac to Mountain Lion in August and ever since it will no longer connect to my Windows 7 user account without a passwrod. I DO NOT USE A PASSWORD ON MY WINDOWS 7 DEFAULT ACCOUNT.  I don't want a password. It's just me, my wife and my infant son. I have no reason to add a password to my account. I don't want to have to enter a darn password every time I start my PC.

My mac will still sign in as a Guest to my PC without a password but not to my primary account.

I followed the steps in this thread to make sure it isn't my PC limiting things:

[Remote desktop without a password](https://superuser.com/questions/106917/remote-desktop-without-a-password)

However, it doesn't matter how I set the **'limit local account use of blank passwords'**  group policy. Either way (enabled or disabled) the mac won't login to my PC account with a blank password.

THIS DEFINITELY CHANGED as a result of upgrading from Snow leopard to Mountain Lion.

Is there any setting I can change on my Mac or PC to allow my Mac to connect to my PC account without having to enter a password as it has always been?

Thanks.

...Dale