# VPS - Lost password and can't use blank pass via remote desktop connection

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, passwords, administrator, vps

I am currently trying to login to my dedicated server, and have forgotten the password.

I've tried many different things, and currently have SSH access. I boot the dedi into rescue mode (For the SSH) and then back into hard drive boot so I can use Remote Desktop Connection (RDC). However, my most recent attempts where to use the following:

At /mnt/Windows/System32/config -> I use chntpw -u Administrator SAM and tried to use option 2... This was edit/set new user password and it failed. Secondly I tried to blank out the password (Option 1) completely, this appeared to have worked, but unfortunately I get an error when trying to connect via RDC saying invalid password. After much research I realized that often remote connections are unable to use blank passwords.

So, I thought I'd go back onto SSH and edit the password to become un-blank, and see if that worked again. But I get this error: "Sorry, unable to edit since password seems blank already (thus no space for it)" and it asks me to login with no password.

I am looking to either A) Set a new password, or B) Just get the damn admin account accessible again via RDC.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`chntpw` comes with a registry editor. As described in the answer ["Remote desktop without a password"](https://superuser.com/questions/106917/remote-desktop-without-a-password), under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` you can create a value `LimitBlankPasswordUse` (type DWORD) and set it to zero.

1. Start with `chntpw -e /mnt/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM`,
2. then `cd` into `\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`,
3. create the value using `nv 4 LimitBlankPasswordUse`.

This should make Windows accept blank passwords for non-console logins upon the next boot.

After which, you have like five minutes to set a new password for Administrator, until one of those vulnerability scanning bots decides to take this as an invitation to your server...

Comment: Managed to do it in a similar way, thank you for your help :)