# Windows refuses to detect mouse/keyboard input

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, bios, mouse

I was away for the weekend and when I came back this morning my PC booted up just fine but I couldn't input anything via mouse or keyboard in Windows. I've already tried rebooting, different usb ports and changing usb settings in the BIOS - but neither has helped. In my BIOS screen both mouse and keyboard work just fine.

I'm on Windows 7 64bit and I have a wireless Microsoft Keyboard/Mouse-Set with a usb dongle (both use the same dongle). My mainboard is an ASUS H81-T. My Setup has been the same for over three month and I've never had any problem nor did I install new software recently. I even updated my BIOS because there was a newer one out and I hoped it maybe will fix the issue but sadly it didn't.

What could be the reason for this behaviour? Has anyone faced similar problems?

**EDIT:**
Just tried another usb keyboard but it also did not work.

Comment: It sounds like the keyboard and mouse are wireless. Do they work fine before Windows boots? Stupid question, I know.

Comment: yeah, they work fine in BIOS and when I boot some Linux distro off USB it also works fine.

Comment: Have you switched the ports while Windows is booted?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Just tried it but it didn't help

Comment: Do memory sticks work? Sounds like the drivers for the USB hub have gone awry...

Comment: @BigChris You may be right! No AutoPlay screen when I put in a stick.

Comment: You may need to boot into Safe Mode and see if the USB drivers get loaded so you can uninstall them (via Device Manager) -> reboot -> let Windows re-install them and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @BigChris USB isn't working in safe mode, either. So no chance to remove drivers. Also I don't think Windows loaded an USB driver from \system32\drivers. At least none of those drivers had a name that made me think it could be a usb driver.

Comment: Does your computer have PS/2 on it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - I was just going to ask that. Looking up the motherboard, it's quite recent so it doesn't have PS/2. This is going to be quite hard to fix... can you remotely control your machine? Remote desktop? You could remote into it to uninstall/re-install the hubs. Alternatively you may need to buy a cheap PCI card with USB ports on. This will prompt Windows to install different drivers but at least you'll have some working USB ports...

Comment: It seems like problem with your CMOS battery. Remove and insert CMOS battery. If it doesn't work change CMOS battery.

Comment: @vembutech I think we've figured out that it's not that.

Comment: @BigChris Yep, youre right: no PS2. I'm currently struggling with RDP. I used [this](http://superuser.com/questions/106917/remote-desktop-without-a-password) to be able to connect to my windows machine that has no password set up, but still after the client has connected I'm asked again to type in my login credentials. Still trying to bypass this..

Comment: Hit F8 right before Windows starts to boot and see if there's anything under Repair your Computer, like System Restore.

Comment: When you RDP you should enter your username and password as "Remote-PC-name\Remote-username" - e.g. `BrokenPC\Username`

Comment: @Zacharee1 System Repair did repair *something*, but nut my USB problem

Comment: @BigChris I was able to RDP into my machine! The Device Manager was showing two exclamation marks for two *USB Root Hub*. I deleted those two and rebooted. Now everything is back to normal! :) I hope this won't happen again... Thank you **ALL** for your great and quick responses!

Comment: Try disabling USB in BIOS if you can, booting Windows and then re-enabling it.

Comment: Put your comment as an answer so the question is answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remotely log in onto my machine using Microsoft Remote Desktop (RDP). The Device Manager was showing two exclamation marks for two *USB Root Hub*. I deleted those two and rebooted. Windows then reinstalled the USB drivers and my mouse and keyboard are working again.