# Windows 7 not receiving input from Logitech G105 keyboard & Logitech B100 mouse, Ubuntu handles it fine

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have used this keyboard/mouse combo for years with no issues. I unplugged both to use elsewhere for a few days. The computer remained on for the entire duration that they were disconnected, sitting on the Windows 7 desktop. When I reconnected them, neither seemed to correctly send their input to the computer. No characters were typed, and the cursor did not move. I rebooted by pressing the reset button on the case (pretty much cuts power and reboots) and the BIOS, Grub2, and Ubuntu all worked perfectly with it. The keyboard and mouse are separate, wired, USB devices. Any thoughts?

Edit: I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/913370/windows-refuses-to-detect-mouse-keyboard-input) and I cannot use RDP to connect and reinstall the USB drivers. When I try, RDP hangs on "Initiating remote connection..."

Comment: Did you try different usb ports?

Comment: Do other keyboards still work? Is there anything relevant in the event viewer? Do they work in safe mode?

Comment: @Moab I have tried most configurations of 2 plugs in 3 ports. I'll try hotswapping, one moment.

Comment: Look in device manager for errors also.

Comment: Hotswapping worked. It's always the simple things. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: Glad you resolved it, you can "answer" your own question using the "your answer" box below if you wish. Include everything you tried plus what worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest potential solution to this kind of problem is to **disconnect the devices in question while Windows is booted, then immediately reconnect them in different ports.**

From what I can tell, this forces Windows to refresh the USB driver, which fixes... whatever strangeness causes this. It worked for me, but it may not work for everyone. Other things to try for similar problems include using Remote Desktop to remotely access Device Manager and clear any alerts next to the devices (thanks to [farosch](https://superuser.com/users/440496/farosch)) and booting in Safe Mode (thanks to [Big Chris](https://superuser.com/users/321172/big-chris)). All of the other advice on [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/913370/windows-refuses-to-detect-mouse-keyboard-input) is also good.