# Access LAN PC remotely but that PC Password is empty

Tags: windows, networking, lan

Are there any method to connect LAN PC call **PC-A** (192.168.1.10) in the same network in another  PC call **PC-B** (192.168.1.11). But First PC **PC-A** password is **empty**!

It can be possible to connect PC-A using PC-B ?

Comment: I mean browse files in explorer window by using \\192.168.1.10

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not share the selected files that you want to access, you could use the hidden share (if it wasn't deactivated).

You could try to access the \192.168.1.10\C$ or D$ depending on the drive letter you want to access.

This does require admin access on the computer. So if the default use doesn't have admin rights or doesn't have a password, you can create a admin account that nobody uses except you to access the files remotly.

This information should be true for Windows xp and 7. I haven't tested on the others version yet.

Answer (score 0):

By default you cannot connect with empty password. Windows will not allow the logon over a network with a blank password.

You can disable blank password restrictions by using a policy. To locate and change this policy:

1. Click Start, point to Run, type gpedit.msc, and then click OK to
   start the Group Policy Editor.
2. Open Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only.
3. Double-click Limit local account use of blank passwords to consol logon only.
4. Click Disabled, and then click OK.
5. Quit Group Policy Editor.

   ```
      NOTE: By default, this policy is on (enabled).
   ```

Further more https://superuser.com/a/106922