# RDP without password Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I want to RDP into my desktop from my tablet.

My desktop account doesn't have a password so it signs in faster. There's a group policy setting to allow remote connections to accounts with no password.

Windows 10 Home Basic does not have `gpedit`. How do I allow RDP with no password?

Comment: Similar question here but for Windows 7: http://superuser.com/questions/106917/remote-desktop-without-a-password the answer illudes to a registry key, even though `gpedit.msc` isn't available, can you see that reg key? There is a possibility that the key may not be the same in Windows 7 vs Windows 10